# How to connect device to IBM cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

I was using Watson IoT platform to connect my IoT device to cloud. But now I do not know how to do it, because Watson IoT platform service was delete. So I want to know How to connect my IoT device to IBM cloud. I want to use MQTT comunication between my IoT gateway and IBM cloud service. Could you please give me some advice how to do it? I do not have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Watson IoT platform was deprecated and withdrawn from IBM Cloud quite a while ago.
There is no direct replacement so you will need to change your application depending on your use case. Check this page for more details [Deprecation of IBM Watson IoT Platform on IBM Cloud](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/IoT?topic=IoT-deprecation)